# Regexp syntax Python

Tags: python, regex

What is the `{%d}` for in these regexp?
I've read: [the re doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) but I could not something about it (except maybe [this part](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#simulating-scanf)) .

```
B = r'( {%d})'

N = r'(\d{%d})'
NB = r'([0-9 ]{%d})'

A = r'(\w{%d})'
AB = r'([a-zA-Z ]{%d})'

AN = r'([a-zA-Z0-9]{%d})'
ANB = r'([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{%d})'

AMT = r'(\d{13}[{}A-R]{1})'

ALL = r'(.{%d})'
```

Comment: A literal {%d} sequence in a raw string literal.

Comment: `%d` is not related to regex but only to C formatted strings. In this ways you can replace the placeholder `%d` (that stands for an integer) later: `'I have %d apples in my bag' % number_of_apples`

Comment: Yes, I've just realized that. I thought it had special meaning. I sometimes forget that r means RAW and not RegEx... Thanks!

Comment: Regex are strings first, regex later. So `r''` doesn't mean it's contents can't be regex.